# How to pass audio data directly to Sphinx4

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I would like to use Sphinx4 for a part of my system. And, I have already tried the HelloWorld demo which uses the microphone directly. Also, I have seen examples about using audio files.

So, my question is that is whether there is any other way to recognize voice? For example, recognize short type data (e.g. a `short[]` buffer).

I cannot find ways other than using the microphone or wav files (audio files).

For example, PocketSphinx has the `processRaw` function which is described in this question ([Input for Pocketsphinx on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566701/input-for-pocketsphinx-on-android)).

Is there no corresponding function in Sphinx4?

Answer (score 1):

To feed data from a byte array you need to do the following:

1. Configure frontend to use [StreamDataSource](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/frontend/util/StreamDataSource.html) instead of Microphone or AudioFileDataSource. You can see LatticeDemo or TranscriberDemo for example how to do that.
2. Create [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) from byte[] array with data
3. Set input stream to use ByteArrayInputStream with setInputStream method of StreamDataSource
4. Run [recognize()](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/recognizer/Recognizer.html#recognize%28%29) to recognize data from byte array

You can succesfully use any data through InputStream, for example input data from a Socket or from a File.